# Computer beeps on bluetooth file transfers - can't stop

Tags: windows-7, audio, file-transfer, bluetooth

I have a Windows 7 Pro computer which is configured to receive a file from another computer (Windows XP) every 30-60 seconds.  This file is a screenshot of the second computer.  We're not allowed to have the second computer connected to any outside network, as it monitors and controls some important industrial processes.  However, we need to be able to view the screen at all times, so we take a screenshot every 30-60 seconds and send it via bluetooth to a web-enabled computer.  Complex, but it works.

Nothing has changed hardware-wise in the last 6 months.  Everything is working fine, but within the last few weeks, the receiving computer (Windows 7) has been beeping (through the main speakers, NOT the PC speaker) whenever bluetooth transfers take place.

This sound is annoying the user.  If he turns the Windows volume control down, the sound is no longer audible, but this is not a practical solution.

I have checked the Notification settings within the Bluetooth configuration window, and they are set to simply "Provide visual notification" and the "audio notification" is disabled. (See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujzQZ.jpg)).

[image: screenshot]

I also checked if any new updates had been installed which could affect the Bluetooth drivers/stack/options.  No updates since 3/2015.

Would appreciate any pointers or suggestions on stopping this beep!

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to silence the Bluetooth notification sounds, without going through all of the pain, of digging for the permission to do so - you can just change the sound, to a silent wave file - as shown in the picture.

Record one second of audio, with all controls at zero; copy this file, to the C:\Windows\media directory; then select it, via the Bluetooth Settings menu.

This menu is for the connection alert sound, but the audio file chosen, is the default for both events. So you can just leave it checked, and the effect is the same for both - no more notification sounds.

[image: Bluetooth Sound]

[This trick also works as a selected privacy ringtone, for phones that lack a "Silent" option, for setting contact tones.]